# Function returns pointer to array with result. How to access this data

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a function imported from dll and defined in ctypes. I set `restype` as `c_void_p`. So now when I call the function, as a result it returns pointer to 32byte array of bytes. How can I convert this pointer to Python bytes type?

Here is the function (it's a `HMAC` from OpenSSL):

```
self.HMAC = self._lib.HMAC
self.HMAC.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
self.HMAC.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
```

EDIT: I've tried replacing `c_void_p` with `c_char_p`. I get some results, but `c_char_p` represents null terminated string, so the results are cut at the point of first 00h. If `HMAC` does not have any zeros in the result than it works perfectly. But this still does not solve my problem.

Comment: `ctypes` has two different types for pointer to character. Use `c_char_p` when you have a pointer to a null-terminated string, `POINTER(c_char)` (aka `LP_c_char`) when you have a pointer to a single character or an arbitrary array of them. Under the covers they're identical, but the `contexts`, indexing, etc. do different things. Of course it's simpler to just use an array instead of a pointer, as Cairnarvon's answer explains, but that's the same as for any array, not special to char arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ctypes.c_void_p` as a return type is usually the wrong thing to do.

For non-nul-terminated string, you should set it to an array of chars of the right size; 32 in your case, so `ctypes.c_char * 32`. The `restype` is a pointer to this, so wrap it in a `ctypes.POINTER`.

You can access the returned value as a `bytes` object using the `value` (or `raw`; it's the same thing in this context) attribute of that pointer's `contents`.

Here's a practical example using [`crypt(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt), which returns a 13-character string:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> crypt = ctypes.CDLL('libcrypt.so').crypt
>>> crypt.argtypes = ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p
>>> crypt.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char * 13)
>>> crypt('tea', 'ea')
<__main__.LP_c_char_Array_13 object at 0x7f7d464f2200>
>>> crypt('tea', 'ea').contents
<__main__.c_char_Array_13 object at 0x7f7d464f2290>
>>> crypt('tea', 'ea').contents.value
b'eauWokonZwxw2'
```

Comment: Thanks.. I made it working. I defined restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char * 32). Latter to convert it to bytes in python code: return hmac[0][:32]

Comment: You _can_ just [`cast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast) from `c_void_p` to the right type (and then go from there to `bytes`) after the fact… but Cairnarvon is right, there's no reason to do so; just specify the right type as the `restype` in the first place.

Comment: @eryksun, good point, re: pointer. It slipped my mind because of C's pointer decay, but you're right.

Comment: @abarnert: I used [:size], because I made whole python function more universal. I declared 64 bytes buffer as restype, to be able to handle different kinds of hash algorithms (algorithm name is passed as function parameter). At the end I just cut byte array to the length of selected hash. 64 bytes give me possibility to handle everything up to SHA512. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Marek: I think you meant to reply to eryksun, not me. And I think Cairnarvon meant to reply to me, not eryksun. But it doesn't matter.

Comment: @abarnert: my comment was actually a reply to a comment eryksun has since deleted, presumably because my edit addressed it.